# Iterate over a object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to iterate over a object in my reactjs but have issues. It does not display any content.

Here is the fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/8e039Ltw/

Reactjs code:-

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: {'male':20, 'female':40}      
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.entries(this.state.items).map(([key, value])=>{
                    <li>{key}</li>                    
                })
            }

      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1):

return is missing in jsx.

Change your render method like below,

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { 
          Object.entries(this.state.items)
            .map(([key, val]) => {
              return <li key={key}>{key}: {val}</li>
            })
        }
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value :

```js
Object.entries(this.state.items).map(([key, value])=>{
    return <li>{key}</li>                    
})
```

When you are wrapping your map in `{` and `}`, you need to return something. It's a function.
When you are using a 'one-line' function, you can omit the return statement :

```js
Object.entries(this.state.items).map(([key, value]) => <li>{key}</li>)
```